Does the science work for why my trolls explode?
When they need to regrow a limb or other body parts their metabolism ramps up and is supplemented by nano machines allowing for rapid regeneration and releasing a lot of waste heat in the process.
This insane ability makes them a nearly perfect super soldier for the current age. But their biggest weakness is taking too much damage. If their bodies sustain too much injury their healing factor can start to run amok as it tries to heal too much all at once and spirals out of control generating too much heat for the nano machines to keep up with, causing a chain reaction of healing, heat damage, healing and so on until eventually the subject violently explodes.
Basically I'm wondering if the science here works IRL? Would rapid healing cause waste heat to build up and could that cause damage to then accumulate which then results in a chain reaction of healing, heating, healing, heating until a violent explosion happens?
If this doesn't work then how can they explode violently?

And all because the beancounters overruled the engineers and insisted that not including a governor in the design will save five full cents per super soldier troll. Seriously speaking, self-powered machines are most usually designed with automatic safeguards which cut, throttle, cap or reduce power when the machine approaches design limits. From the early steam engines to steam and gas turbines to ultra-modern laptops.

If that's how trolls work in your world why does it matter that isn't how things work in a world that doesn't have trolls at all?

Suggest that you reconsider the [hard-science] tag - there is insufficient detail provided in the question for calculations and there are no real-world regenerating organisms that work this way for there to be published papers about.  The answers so far don't meet the tag requirement, but I can't see how any answer could.

You seem to have solved the energy problem when regrowing limbs. What do you do for the materials? You need matter to grow anything. As said in an answer, you're so far out of reality it can be pretty much whatever you want it to be. Do not worry too much about reality when writing. It can add a beautiful finish on your story if done right. But it is too easily restrictive, putting the story you want to tell in danger.

Actually the energy problem for regrowing limbs and materials all come form the same source, the trolls can eat just about anything as food. There's some things their body can't break down, they're still based on humans but they can eat stuff like dead people or pure metal even, nothing toxic though like uranium.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. You're not asking for help solving a problem, which is mandatory for Stack Exchange questions. You've already built your world and now you want to know, what? If your fiction and/or fantasy expresses scientific fact? That's not what we do per the [help]. Worse is the use of the [tag:hard-science] tag, which you are abusing. It's purpose is to constrain answers to a question about a problem - not to force a specific type of analysis of an inappropriate idea review.

I'm not going to lie I figured the question was within the rules "How can I get my Trolls to explode violently with what I have as a reason in setting." If this doesn't work then how can I make them explode violently? If it's still not within the rules then please let me know.

You have magic in your world (nanobots being essentially that) and you're asking how the magic operates by real world logic. We don't know. We don't even care - you are the author who created the magic. You decide how it works. IRL if a machine overheats, it tends to stop working. But who knows how those those nanobots work with their apparently infinite heat output and infinite work bandwidth (more damage makes them work faster, after all).

I'm not treating them as magic in my setting, I'm using all the knowledge I can find on how they could work or be used IRL to base my nano machines off of, as in this article and others.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanorobotics while I do have actual magic in setting, this is not one of them and will still have to work via our own natural universes rules. Could I have worded my question better? Yes, and I'm editing it to be as clear & as concise as I can make it. Being autistic however hinders this because while I might see this as a "normal" question other's can be confused by it.

I’m voting to close this question because – as other have concluded – you are already using magic liberally. And, yes, you are using magic, as per Arthur C Clarke's definition: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic". So asking for "hard science" when you have already thrown that out the window by using magic, makes this question unanswerable. You magic:ed their healing ability into existence, then there is no reason to not also invent weaknesses in this magic.

"I'm not treating them as magic in my setting," let's differentiate here nanobotics is a thing that exists. At least in theory. However, we do not have nanobots that give you a healing factor. That's "magic". There are several things that make the nanobots "magical"  - as I said, the seemingly unbound thermal production. That's simply not how machines operate IRL. They don't produce infinite heat. They stop. Or are damaged by the heat. However, it could be how your nanobots work. But it's circular again - they work the way they've been described to work.

The thermal production isn't a direct result of just the nanomachines though. It's a combination of the fact that rapid healing releases heat combined with the nano machines heating up due to working in basically an overdrive state. My understanding of machines overheating could be wrong I will admit but I don't see that as magical in nature, seeing as all machines can and do overheat if used in excess.

Most don't cause explosions. And the ones that do, don't have the characteristics of a nanobot. As in, they tend to be big machines dealing with a lot of power and/or being combustible. Which a nano-scale robot is not going to be. Consider a computer - if it overheats a lot (and cooling doesn't work, nor emergency shutdown and other protections) then it's not going to blow up. It'd probably fry some of the components and at most catch on fire (even that is quite abnormal). You want even more spectacular results from a machine magnitudes smaller.

True they are smaller, I guess I figured with the high concentration of them, it would add up to something big if that makes sense.

The explosives explode because too much energy is released in short time and restricted volume.
So far your soldiers will boil themselves to death, if the nanites get enough power input.
If you want them to blast you can achieve that through nanites overloading. As the nanobot get overloaded - with extensive rebuild demands it's more than possible - it cannot handle it's fuel and go boom. This nano-scale blast triggers more than two another almost-overloaded nanites and you have nice chain reaction like in the Manhattan project.
On the other hand this is a major design flaw compared to the Death Star's core vulnereability. Decent testing would overlad the soldier and make him go blast and throw the project either to dump or back-to-sketchboard.

That actually would make sense seeing as these guys are experimental super soldiers who never got deployed to the battlefield. I just looked and realized I didn't explain that part at all in the original post  I was a little too excited to find a place to talk about science and world building  but that actually makes sense in setting seeing as these guys are being mass produced for experimental/testing purposes before the great cataclysmic collapse happens.

Could be a feature not a bug! If a troll is too injured to be useful it triggers the explosive chain reaction. Troll goes boom, chunks of troll with seed nanites get spread all over the ground. 99.9% of those nanites run out of fuel and go defunct, but a small % manages to take root, and grow into a mold-like nanofab that produces a new troll. Thus, the more trolls you kill, the more trolls grow out of the ground, and if you keep fighting them then eventually your entire ecosystem is just a pile of trolls.

@GoingDurden Hmm... Nice bug-to-feature process or even "task failed sucessfully". With some ballancing it might be working setup. Your suggestion seems to be and overkill.

@Crowley, the simplest balancing limit would be just realism; realistic nanobots are unlikely to be all that powerful. Just dosing the scattered remains of the troll with some strong chemicals, adhesives or just using a flamethrower should be enough to "purify" the ground and destroy the seed. and even without it, nanobots would not be able to grow a troll without sufficient biomass to convert, so battling trolls in an urban area, a desert or during winter would be pretty safe.

The Boring answer - it does if you say it does
You are in a world with:

Trolls
Super soldiers
Nanomachines

So, an explosion due to story reasons is entirely within the realm of possibility.
The Frame Challenge Answer
This is a common question - trying to make something science based that really doesn't need a science based explanation.
The Trolls explode on Death. End of.
You don't really need to elaborate on this, except if there are story reasons for doing so (e.g. your characters need to kill a troll in such a way that doesn't cause them to explode).
If they are designed to be supersoldiers, then having them explode on death may be a desirable trait (preventing capture by the enemy etc.)
However - for a better explanation - I wouldnt say a build up of excess heat - I would say that there are byproducts of the regeneration process that are explosive (Hydrogen would be the easiest) - with a normal wound, this is slowly expelled over time, but with sufficient damage too much is generated to process, which then meets an ignition source (the Nanobots might generate tiny arcs of electricity) and kaboom.

I'm not even sure a hydrogen explosion would be necessary (although it is a very good explanation!). If there's a certain threshold where the nanites' cooling systems can't keep them in perfect thermal equilibrium, billions of nanites times a millikelvin per second per nanite of heating equals a very large amount of heat in a very small amount of time.

I honestly love the idea of byproducts building up, that kinda means the people fighting it are on a time limit. They need to kill it as fast as possible with a powerful first strike or else risk playing a deadly game of chicken. As for I try to make it a science based explanation, I honestly just want to do my best to use current or cutting edge science and scientific theory to make my work as Hard as I can. I don't mind using some "magic" technology because I do plan on having Fantasy elements on this book but still, I love using Hard Science where I can.

Not possible
Even given the speculative nature of the technologies in question, we can rule this out.
High explosives burn quickly, producing a pressure wave that creates the explosion. You describe a thermal runaway situation though, which is inherently going to be slow.
That leaves us with the low explosive route. The reaction process needs to happen in a sealed container, building up reaction gases, until the container loses structural integrity. The classic example would be high-pressure steam, which in fact is the only way your trolls could explode, as their blood boils from the heat applied by the nano machines.
The problem for your scenario is that there's no containment method. At most you're talking puffs of steam as skin ruptures, but their skin can't be solid enough to hold the steam under any kind of real pressure, otherwise their skin wouldn't be able to flex as they move.
I did consider a next step. What if the trolls wore sealed battle armour, like a Space Marine?
This has the same basic problem though - however thick the armour plate is, you're always going to need joints, and when the troll's blood boils off, those joints are going to be weak spots that'll act like safety relief valves. You wouldn't want to put your hand in the hot steam, the same way as you wouldn't put your hand over a kettle spout, but like the kettle it's just going to steam and not explode.

Thank you! But also dang! That means I've got to go back to the drawing board but it is actually neat to know that they'd puff out steam. That can be useful to know and it could still be used in an interesting way

@Altarious You're welcome. :) If you can think of a way where the skin would be "cooked" first to become solid and sealed (perhaps some kind of polymerization, perhaps the nanomachines themselves) then perhaps you could get some shrapnel from that when the blood boils, but I don't see how it could be more than a small annoyance for people close to it. High-pressure steam explosions need the kind of pressure that comes with steel pressure vessels, and skin (even augmented) probably won't do that.

Hmm you know I could make it so the nanites harden like steel when exposed to sunlight! That could actually work as a nod to their mythology and as a way for pressure to build up!

@Altarious I'm still not sure you'd get actual steel strength. It might spoil the day of anyone immediately next to the body though.

true. Honestly it might just be better to have the knights shove a bomb down their throats and blow them up that way. Might not be as spectacular but it would definitely be interesting.

@Altarious In the same way as the infamous blowing-up-a-whale news story. Body parts scattering the area might not be popular with everyone, especially anyone who has to clean bits of troll out of their armour afterwards. :)

Easier fix is to have bone marrow made of something that expands when heated… that’s a contained substance that could send bone fragments out explosively.

If you say that that's how it works, that's how it works.
Nanotechnology like healing-factor nanobots and the like are so far out of the current grasp of humanity that even talking about it invokes science-fiction automatically. Constructing a single microscopic device that can perform a simple task (like detecting a chemical) is already an extremely-expensive task that requires industrial-grade equipment and high-tech engineering. If you want to build robots at a thousandth of that scale that can do incredibly complex tasks (detecting damaged tissue and automatically repairing it without any workable biomass other than what's immediately available to it), you're talking at least a century into the future.
Keep in mind that a nanobot measuring 1 micrometer or 1000 nanometers across (a twenty-fifth of the width of a human cell, and sort of the upper limit for what can be called a nanobot) is only a few hundred thousand atoms across. Constructing a nanobot of that scale would literally entail choosing which atoms and which electrons go where, then making it happen. At that scale we can barely build single transistors, let alone a complex, thinking, biomedical-operation-capable machine. If you want the latter, you'll need to somehow program billions of bytes of pattern recognition, operation programming, and sensor reading into a much-smaller number of atoms, which might not even be physically informationally possible. DNA can fit a lot of information into it, but the processor is often more physically-complex than the hard drive...

My point is just that this is not really in the scope of useful worldbuilding: you have a cool thing in your world that contributes in a good way to your story, but it isn't really in the realm of actual realism. That's okay. Just wave some hands and let cool but unrealistic things be cool, because if you try and explain this one with real science, you're gonna confuse your audience more than entertain them.
I do dabble in computer stuff, and I would say that yeah if there isn't a failsafe built in then the nanites could essentially work themselves to overheating trying to do too much. But I would also say that if you're intelligent and powerful enough to build nanomachines of this quality, you're probably also intelligent enough to create a failsafe to prevent explosions, unless the soldier exploding upon their death is by design for one reason or another; quoth AlexP, the explosion might happen "... all because the beancounters overruled the engineers and insisted that not including a governor in the design will save five full cents per super soldier troll". It's not unreasonable to think that that might be a natural consequence of the nanites having too much to do; my processor certainly heats up quite a bit when I try and run Minecraft and Chrome at the same time, and you have probably on the order of a few billion processors working right next to each other without good cooling systems.

Yes actually this is the result of oversight for the sake of saving money and getting a cheap product that does "just as good as the real thing" combined with a few other things people have explained here it makes perfect sense in the setting that these guys are the end product.

Warning: Science is not very hard.
These trolls need high-energy fuel to do what they do. Both regeneration and general super-soldiering require energy that is more concentrated than sugar.
I don't know what would be the best fuel, but let us say nitroglycerin.
Before each mission they drink enough nitrog to last the mission, with some extra to avoid running out.  This is stored in small bladders throughout the body.
As long as they are alive, their biochemistry keeps the nitrog stable, but when they die, they become bombs.  And the nanites heating up is the fuse.

I'll say right now this is great! It makes chemical and logical sense for the setting.
